# Finding extremal for changing boundary conditions

Tags: calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

I need to find the extremal for:

$$ J[y] = \int_{0}^{1}(1+x)(y')^2 ~ dx $$ with $y(0) = 0$ and $y(1)=1$. I then need to find the extremal if the boundary condition at $x = 1$ changed to $y'(1) = 0$.

So far I've created an Euler-Lagrange equation and gotten it down to

$$ 2y''+x2y''+ 2y' = 0.$$
$$y''=(-2y')/(x+2)$$

this is where I think I'm going wrong, because I don't think I should be trying to integrate a side that has both $y'$ and $x$, I got this but I don't think it's right:

$$y'=(-2y'x)/(x+2)+c$$

If you could help me solve the Euler properly I think I can do the other bit fine by myself

EDIT:

$$v=y'$$

$$y''=v'=dv/dx=dv/dy* dy/dx = V*dv/dy $$

$$v'(1+x)=-1$$

$$v'=-1/(1+x) = y'' $$

$$ y' = -ln(x+1) + c $$

$$ y = x -(x+1)ln(x+1)+cx+d$$

From $y(0) =0$ and $y(1)=1$

=> $$y = x -(x+1)(ln(x+1))+2xln2$$

Comment: If your equation is correct you can substitute as: $y'=u$, then $y''=u'$, thus you have a first order d.e.

Comment: @ZGperx I tried substitution in my edit, is that done correctly for the first part of the question?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct to me!

Answer (score 1):

Lagrangian
$$L~=~(1+x)\dot{y}^2.$$
Momentum
$$p~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{y}}~=~2(1+x)\dot{y}$$
is conserved since $y$ is a [cyclic variable](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_coordinates).
So
$$\dot{y}~=~\frac{p}{2(1+x)},$$
or
$$y(x)~=~ \frac{p}{2}\ln|1+x|+C.$$
The lower BC $y(0)=0$ leads to $C=0$.

The upper BC $y(1)=1$ leads to $p=2/\ln 2$.

The upper BC $\dot{y}(1)=0$ leads to $p=0$.